# Help with a Test code on specific Method

Tags: unit-test, selectlist

I'm facing difficulties to test a method, I'm assigning a string depending on the option selected, and when I'm trying to test this method does not recognize the options.

```
public List<SelectOption> getlength(){
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();            
    if(var_SystemOfMeasurement =='Imperial System'){//previous option selected
        cpl.Length_Units__c = 'Yards';//value assigned
        options.add(new SelectOption('','--Length--'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('36','36'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('18','18'));
    }
    else if((cpl.Currency__c == 'USD' || cpl.Currency__c == 'CAD') && var_SystemOfMeasurement == 'Metric System'){
        cpl.Length_Units__c = 'Meters';
        options.add(new SelectOption('','--Length--'));            
        options.add(new SelectOption('33','33'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('16.5','16.5'));
    }
    else if((cpl.Currency__c == 'EUR' || cpl.Currency__c == 'GBP') && var_SystemOfMeasurement == 'Metric System'){
        cpl.Length_Units__c = 'Meters';
        options.add(new SelectOption('','--Length--'));            
        options.add(new SelectOption('30','30'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('15','15'));
    }
    return options;
```

I'm trying to test the previous code using

```
@isTest
public class Zone_Tape_Controller_Test {

    static TestMethod void Zone_Tape_Controller(){

        //Test VisualForce page
        PageReference pg = new PageReference('/Zone_Tape');
        test.setCurrentPage(pg);

        //Insert Account
        Account acc = new  Account(name = 'Test CAD Name',Company_Code__c = 'GBC',Price_Level__c = 'Ammeraal',ShippingCity = 'Miami',ShippingCountry = 'US',BillingCountry = 'US');
        insert acc;
        system.debug('acc===>'+acc);

        //Insert Product Fabric ETCH
           Product2 pro = new Product2();
           pro.Family = 'Fabric';
           pro.name = '100-3 ETCH';
           //pro.Zone_Tape__c = TRUE;
           pro.ProductCode = '3FE03ST040';
           //pro.IsActive = TRUE;
           insert pro;
        system.debug('pro===>'+pro);
        system.debug('Width===>'+pro.Max_Width__c);

        //Insert Adhesive
           Extra_Material__c ext = new Extra_Material__c();
           ext.name = 'STD-DS-2';
           insert ext;
        system.debug('ext===>'+ext);

        //Doble Side Zone Tape
           Customer_s_Price_List__c CPL_DS = new Customer_s_Price_List__c();
           CPL_DS.Account__c = acc.Id;
           CPL_DS.Price_of__c = 'Zone Tape';
           CPL_DS.Currency__c = 'CAD';
           CPL_DS.System_Of_Measurement__c = 'Imperial System';
           CPL_DS.Product_Description__c = pro.id;
           CPL_DS.Width_Imp_Open__c = 3;
           CPL_DS.Length_Units__c = 'Yards';
           CPL_DS.Long_Imperial__c = 36;
           CPL_DS.Type_Of_Adhesive__c = ext.Id;
           CPL_DS.ZT_Adhesive_Width_Imp__c = 1;
           insert CPL_DS;
           system.debug('CPL_DS===>'+CPL_DS);

        ApexPages.currentPage().getparameters().put('accid',acc.id);

        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new 
        ApexPages.StandardController(CPL_DS);

        Zone_Tape_Controller tst = new Zone_Tape_Controller(sc);

        tst.getZT_Type();
        tst.getSystemOfMeasurement();
        tst.getListGroups();
        tst.getlength();
        tst.getPriceOf();
        tst.getEtchFabric();
        tst.getAdhesive();
        tst.getLiner();

        tst.var_ZT_Type='Double Side Adhesive';
        system.assertEquals(tst.var_ZT_Type, 'Double Side Adhesive');

        List<SelectOption> options = tst.getEtchFabric();
        system.assertNotEquals(null, options, '100-3 ETCH');

        List<SelectOption> options1 = tst.getAdhesive();
        system.assertNotEquals(null, options1, 'STD-DS-2');

        List<SelectOption> options2 = tst.getLiner();
        system.assert(!options2.isEmpty(), ' ');

        List<SelectOption> options3 = tst.getlength();
        system.assertNotEquals(null, options3, 36);

    }

}
```

Any help will be welcome.

Comment: What happens when you call `tst.getlength();`? What assertions is your test code making? How do they fail? Please *edit your question* to provide more details.

Comment: Hi David, thanks... I did--->  List<SelectOption> options3 = tst.getlength();
        system.assertNotEquals(null, options3, 36); but it doesn't come through up to the end... just stopping at the assigned string...

Comment: In a test, you generally need to _explicitly_ set up the data and environment for your test. How is `var_SystemOfMeasurement` normally set in your code? Are you replicating that in your test? Your conditionals also require some values to be set in `cpl`. Are you creating an instance of an SObject and assigning it to `cpl` in your test?

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the actual test class being discussed. As clearly evidenced by the comments, this is going to be difficult to debug without the actual test class.

Comment: I just post the test code... also, var_SystemOfMeasurement {get; set;} is a variable part of a SelectOption method

Answer (score 2):

Your test does not truly test anything, because every single one of your assertions is just a null check or a tautology (showing that `a == a`). Since your code isn't supposed to return `null`, all this demonstrates is that the Salesforce `new` and `==` operators work correctly.

You are not getting complete test coverage on your `getlength()` method because your test code does not create the conditions for all of the branches of your `if` statements to be executed. A good test class will create *multiple* data sets, and execute `getlength()` with inputs for `var_SystemOfMeasurement` and `Currency__c` that cause each `if` statement to evaluate both its `if` (true) and `else` (false) branches.

This is the only way to get full test coverage, but it's not truly useful unless you couple this preparation of data with *real* assertions that check the values returned by `getlength()` and your other methods, and ensure that they match what is expected for the input values.